# Extracting from patch lists only those possibly relevant (with regards to a given install)

Tags: text-processing, make, patch

I am used to downloading **very dense** changelogs like [this one (linux-5.4.211 log)](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.4.211), this in order to carefully decide for each change if it is pertinent on some system of mine or not. (*1)

Of course, considering such monsters, I am never concerned by more than what ? 5 % of the changes… and the higher the release, the less (*2).
Even… I have always read that sort of things entirely… (－‸ლ)

But I am getting old… old and lazier… Could anyone help me **filtering from these lists only the parts my systems could be concerned with ?**

---

OK, I realize you could legitimally ask : *How can I get the precise knowledge about what could actually concern my systems ? :* I myself wonder :-P

**A :** Can I assume that, as part of whatever source tree of whatever *honest* distribution of whatever *honest* software which build being governed by some *honest* makefile **, the list of whatever.o files produced by some make represents the list of object code my system is actually concerned with ?**

**B :** In case of positive answer to A, I could grep the associated patch list (in the example given of kernel sources [this one (linux_5.4.211 patch)](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/patch-5.4.211.xz). (Nothing more than a huge collection of `diff --git`) for `whatever.c` or `whatever.h` (assuming it is C-code only in the precise example) then : **How could I relate these finds to my primary concern of filtering the changelog ?**

---

BTW any kernel hacker is welcome here for suggesting a better approach. But my impression being that we get here around more shell/regexp/awk true gurus, please do compete! (it's more fun)
Whatever suggestion will be welcome, whatever the language.
I do of course accept (some) amount of false-positive (algo not filtering changes I am not actually concerned with). As far as I can reduce the list by at least 4/5 I'll be happy.
However amount of false-negative should equal to… null!

**I will award a-posteriori a +100 bounty on the answer that will provide the less amount of false-positive.**

---

*1 : Because my softwares are heavily patched by custom patches, upstream patches might not, at a given time, be appropriate.

*2 : Taking the example of linux sources, since most of the code and therefore most of the changes concern drivers of devices that never will get plugged into my systems.  Not to say kde where most of the changes are related to the wayland backend when my systems are X11 only.

Comment: Does the initial input *have* to be a patch, rather than a git repository?

Comment: @StephenKitt : Absolutely nothing is constrained in that question. Only the result is important : Saving my time manually parsing huge text files ! The initial input can be whatever you like. I have only been reporting here the kinds of inputs I have usually worked with for ages… I'm not that old to not change my habits…  ;-)

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for bothering and for the tips for making my question more workable. And you are correct,  I do realise how **B/** could look like a job post. **However** the B part is explicitly specified *"in case of positive answer to A"* Meaning that in case I can't assume, the B part is not a job post, it is just utter chimeric nonsense. And **A is not a job post**, its an honest true question from the honest contributor I think I am here. As soon I can get A ACKED, I WILCO with your demand with no delay.